# Linux Active Directory Authentication without domain name?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ssh

Is there a way of authentication Linux users to Windows Active Directory without using the server domain name.

Currently the syntax that I use to log in is this ssh Domain\user@ipaddress

all I want to do is this ssh user@ipaddress

Is there a way of doing this? I've been looking online and cannot find much information.

The package that I am using to do this is Likewise-Open, and it works no problem just have to put in the Domain name.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/likewise-open.html

> To make likewise-open use a default domain, you can add the following
>   statement to /etc/samba/lwiauthd.conf:
>
> `winbind use default domain = yes`
>
> Then restart the likewise-open daemons:
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/likewise-open restart`

This assumes that you only have one domain and are authenticating against a domain controller in that domain. If you want to authenticate by default with a cross-domain then this most likely won't work (and you should really have joined the machine to the other domain).

Comment: On newer version of Likewise Open, at least for me, I did this by modifying the *registry key* `AssumeDefaultDomain` to `dword:00000001` using the `edit-reg` program.

Comment: So I did what you said however, it doesn't seem to work. Well firstly there was no samba directory so I installed samba, then created the file lwiauth.conf myself and added that line. So something wrong I did?

Comment: @user213498 - do you have edit-reg? You can try what I wrote earlier in the comment and then run `lwsm refresh lsass` to refresh your configuration.